# Miktex Package Manager Update leads to SSL Connect Error

Tags: miktex-update

After a couple of installs, and uninstalls, of the Miktex (version 2.9.6643-x64) on Windows 7, and following

(1) some recommended changes of environment variables (in another question) and

(2)  tried the installation and update with and without a proxy, it appears that the "SSL connect error" remains consistent.

This appears to be a bug with the latest Miktex release, since I have not had any problems with the previous vintage.

Comment: Then add an issue to the MiKTeX issue tracker at GitHub. This site is not a good place for this type of questions as one can't reproduce and analyse it easily.

Comment: In particular bug reports are always better addressed at the developer so you can make sure they actually know about it. Not all developers are active here and even fewer can read all questions here.

Comment: Ulrike: I will do that. moewe: Thanks for the advice